# C# Process is not restoring to task bar after form is closed

Tags: c#, process

I have this Form5 and When i load it, is supposed to load google chrome into this window form if chrome is already running or not then is going to start a new process.

Then issue stands at when im closing the Form5 then chrome is not being unembedded from the window form and as you can see on **Form5_FormClosed** is the code that is supposed to restore the window back to task bar but nothing happens and sometimes after 1 of 100 is working. What im doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TrinityItemCreator
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        private string urlDestination;

        private Process myprocess;

        public Form5(string urlTarget)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            urlDestination = urlTarget;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        // HWND Constants
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

        // P/Invoke
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            if (pname.Length != 0) // chrome is already opened
            {
                //Process.Start("chrome", urlDestination);
                Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                {
                    if (theprocess.ProcessName == "chrome")
                    {
                        SetParent(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Handle);
                        int left = 1;
                        int top = 1;
                        int width = 876;
                        int height = 656;

                        SetWindowPos(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOP, left, top, width, height, 0);
                        myprocess = theprocess;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myprocess = Process.Start("chrome", urlDestination);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                SetParent(myprocess.MainWindowHandle, panel2.Handle);
                int left = 1;
                int top = 1;
                int width = 876;
                int height = 656;

                SetWindowPos(myprocess.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOP, left, top, width, height, 0);
            }
        }

        private void Form5_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
                SetParent(myprocess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
                ShowWindow(myprocess.MainWindowHandle, 3); // maximize back
                ShowWindow(myprocess.MainWindowHandle, 2); // minimize to taskbar
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
        }

        private void ButtonMyTemplates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bump, having same problem!